# Google will not work on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gmail

I cannot seem to connect to the google.com domain - **AT ALL** - using Mac OS X (10.5.8)

I have tried Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, all of which refuse to connect to google.com, mail.google.com, OR gmail.com

However, I know it is not my physical connection, because I can successfully log into Gmail from Linux Mint with Firefox and from Windows 7 with Firefox or Chrome.

Both OS's were run as VMs on my Mac too, to make things more interesting...

Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: What error do you get when trying to connect? Any odd DNS settings that you are aware of?

Comment: *Just* Google? Or is the internet not working in general?

Comment: @musicfreak: No, it's *just* Google.
@Arjan: Nothing I'm aware of...

Comment: And now it works fine! I really don't get it...

Comment: Did you recently install any interesting plugins from any interesting websites?

Comment: @NSD: Nope. I closed my Macbook, went to dinner, then when I came back it worked.

Comment: Wow, the Apple/Google relationship seems to be really souring...

Comment: Always simply first reboot all your equipment if "nothing changed" and "things suddenly don't work anymore"...

Comment: @Arjan: "Reboot at first and see if you still have the problem", most often working solution, recommended by generations of sysadmins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could also be a DNS issue on your OS X box if pinging the google.com domain fails. Try an IP address directly like (this is what google.com resolves to for me):

```
ping 208.69.34.231
```

If you get a response you know that you need to check your DNS settings.
If your ISP's DNS servers are to blame you can use the excellent free servers at [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/).

Comment: As for *"if pinging the google.com domain fails"* note that a ping can fail for many reasons, even if a website can still be reached without any problems. But indeed: if `ping google.com` fails but `ping 208.69.34.231` is just fine, then it's some DNS issues (like the DNS does not know Google at all, or like a few Google servers might be out of order but the DNS does not know about that yet and returns the IP addresses of the broken machines).

Answer (score 1):

Try pinging the domain you're trying to reach.
Open Terminal and type

```
ping www.google.com
```

Maybe that'll give you some info.

Also check out your hosts file at /etc/hosts if there's nothing dodgy there.